# CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-758.1.6/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:289)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use AFNetworing and SDWebimage in my project, but when I run my APP in simulator，here are some pictures can't load,console show me some information like this:

```
 1341: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-758.1.6/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:289)
```

I've search this issue in stack overflow,someone say the reason is SDWebimage get a http image (not https image),and I find my image path like this

```
http://cdn.duitang.com/uploads/blog/201408/31/20140831205827_xiQhE.jpeg_webp
```

I've handle the image path like this

```
http://cdn.duitang.com/uploads/blog/201408/31/20140831205827_xiQhE.jpeg
```

The result is some picture can load but some can't.
It's really make me confused for a long time, who can help me,thanks a lot~

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025929/cfnetwork-internal-error-cfnetworkinternal-h478

Comment: thanks a lot,I've solved